# How to hide column in div based table

Tags: jquery, css, html

I use JQuery. I need to hide column of table (div based). In following example, i need to hide/show the textboxes on click of check box. And after hiding text boxes, paragraph 2nd will move to upper side. On the same, i do not need to change the position of customer name & address.

HTML code is

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" />Check it, if customer has no company.
<span>Paragraph 1st Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </span>
        <div class="divTable">
             <div class="headRow">
                <div class="divCell" align="center">Company Name</div>
                <div  class="divCell">Customer Name</div>
                <div  class="divCell">Customer Address</div>
             </div>
            <div class="divRow">
                <div class="divCell" align="center"><input type="text" /></div>
                <div class="divCell" align="center">Customer Name</div>
                <div class="divCell" align="center">Customer Address</div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow">
                <div class="divCell" align="center"><input type="text" /></div>
           </div>
            <div class="divRow">
                <div class="divCell" align="center"><input type="text" /></div>
           </div>
      </div>
<p>Paragraph 2nd Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </P>
```

CSS is,

```
.divTable
{
    display:  table;
    width:auto;
    background-color:#eee;
    border:1px solid  #666666;
    border-spacing:5px;
}

.divRow
{
   display:table-row;
   width:auto;

}

.divCell
{
    float:left;
    display:table-column;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#ccc;

}
```

How can i hide the column of table (div based)?

Comment: Why don't you use <table> for table? Yes, using TABLE element is a bad practice for layout but it's still the right thing for tabular data.

Comment: Whole site is developed in Div.

Comment: @Ozzone: You only want to hide text boxes or the labels too?

Comment: @Ozzone: See the my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12313465/1516616) below. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(){
    $("input[type=text]").toggle();
});
```

Comment: After implemeting above code, structure of Div is destrioyed. Coloum 2 is merged with coloum 1.

Answer (score 0):

try

`$('input[type=text]').css('visibility','hidden');`

instead of hiding them like this

```
$('#chk')​​​​.click(function(){
    if($('input[type=text]').css('visibility')=='hidden')
    {
       $('input[type=text]').css('visibility','');
    }
    else
    {
        $('input[type=text]').css('visibility','hidden')
    }
});​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4SQC/)

Comment: Thanks for half solution. After hiding textbox, how can paragraph 2nd  move to upper side?

Comment: Thanks for half solution sir. In your soultion, whole textboxes were hide. But, the paragraph 2nd is not moved to upper side.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like in this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yUEFd/)

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(){
    $(".divTable").toggle();
});​
```

Comment: Sorry sir, in your soultion, whole div is disappeared. I need to hide only text boxes and move the paragraph 2nd to upper side.

Comment: Where to upper side? Can you elaborate? Inside the div (the grey area) or beneath 1st paragraph? And what about the labels of input boxes?

Comment: After hiding the text box, i need to hide gray area. Input labels remains as it is.